# Different behaviour of navigationBar prefersLargeTitles for iPhone8+ and iPhone X

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar, preferslargetitles

The same ViewController navigation bar for two devices is shown in different modes at launch. This navigation bar is collapsed in iPhone8+. But it is possible to expand it. How to fix it? I've got 'safe area' constraints.

The content size is much more than screen size in both cases.

iPhoneX

[image]

iPhone8+

[image]

`navigationController?.navigationItem.largeTitleDisplayMode = .always`

[image]

Comment: did u try this
navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true

Comment: @Aleem, of course, in the title of the question I mentioned about it